# « J'ai payé le tout 2 euros. »

Tags: vocabulaire

> J'ai acheté un croissant et une baguette de pain. J'ai payé le tout 2 euros.

C'est une phrase de mon livre de grammaire française. Pourquoi le verbe « ai payé » est-il suivi de deux objets sans aucune préposition ? Est-il donc possible de dire « payer [quelque chose] [montant] » ?

Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oui c'est tout à fait possible, cette phrase contient à la fois un complément d'objet direct (le tout) et un complément circonstanciel de mesure (2 euros).

Comment: "Baguette de pain" me semble usuel (France métropolitaine, région ouest)

Comment: @mcadorel OK, c'est probablement le cas dans certaines régions alors. Réponse mise à jour.